# Firejail and connecting to the Internet through an host OpenVPN client

Tags: networking, openvpn, firejail

If the host is an OpenVPN client, how would I set up Internet access for a
firejail sandbox with its own network namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time (Jan. 2017) there does not seem to be a de facto solution.  The subject was discussed in quite some detail in this post [Implement X11 isolation](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/57) - not sure if there has been anything further since.

`firejail` returns the following error with a tun `--net` device, not something a VM would ordinarily have a problem with:

```
Error: the software is not supported for /31 networks
```

A TAP interface could be bridged, there are TAP VPNs out there ([ibVPN](https://www.ibvpn.com/) for one I think).

I have implemented a ssh forwarding (socks) proxy based on instructions given in this article [Firejail with Tor HOWTO](https://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2016/12/12/firejail-with-tor-howto/).

See this post also on setting up an HTTP proxy [redirect traffic from bridge to http proxy](https://superuser.com/questions/1172607/redirect-traffic-from-bridge-to-http-proxy/1172625).

Edit 17 Feb '17:

OpenVPN integration https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/59